# HIVE UDF class missing

Tags: class, hive, user-defined-functions

I have created below UDF functions :

```
package co.hive.udf;

import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import sun.misc.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;


public class encryptHivecolumn extends UDF {
    private static final String ALGO = "AES";
     private static final byte[] keyValue = 
                new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't',
        'S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };
     public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
            Key key = generateKey();
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
            @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
            String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
            return encryptedValue;
        }


        private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
            Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
            return key;
    }




}
```

And created JAR from eclipse. I added JAR file from eclipse too and it says added to classpath but when I create temporary function it says class not found.

Comment: have you created a fat jar (jar with all the dependancies) or thick jar.  if you are not  sure what I am talking about, check the size of the jar. if it's in KB's it doesn't have necessary dependacies, if it's in MB's they you are good to go.

Comment: Could you paste a stacktrace, also how are you adding jar

Comment: I was able to create JAR and run it but now I am getting below error. it is enrypting correctly if I just run select statement but when I create table from the select it is inserting NULL values in the table. please see details below. how to avoid this issue where columns are beloming null in create table as statement.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create JAR and run it but now I am getting below error. it is enrypting correctly if I just run select statement but when I create table from the select it is inserting NULL values in the table. please see details below. how to avoid this issue where columns are becoming null in create table as statement.

```
hive> select id,Decrypt(Encrypt(firstname)),lastname,city  from plikhi.stagging_encrypt limit 10;
OK
1       Theodore        KQcNniTorf      Des Moines
2       Franklin        u6792WT1MZ      Jefferson City
3       Dwight  suR6IQZwLJ      Charleston
4       Ronald  yeMmNHuQca      Providence
5       Woodrow XE3bw5Cjib      Juneau
6       Richard PQOXrqHyCP      Baton Rouge
7       Lyndon  IrKwoTqXnR      Carson City
8       William 5TdDMqAXrX      Providence
9       George  OtWW4BdFVv      Raleigh
10      Harry   NiRnATHIWo      Augusta
Time taken: 0.078 seconds, Fetched: 10 row(s)

hive> create table Encrypt_Test as select id,Encrypt(firstname) as firstname,lastname,city  from plikhi.stagging_encrypt limit 10;

Query ID = plikhi.admin_20180907082938_f71da154-8c3c-46d5-88d4-b794712199e8
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1535856819605_0058)

Moving data to directory hdfs://vtorbdapc01.devad.moneris.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/encrypt_test
Table default.encrypt_test stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=10, totalSize=507, rawDataSize=497]
OK
Time taken: 10.161 seconds
hive> select * from Encrypt_Test;
OK
```

1       BiOPF4LrWbPHDWRbiSV4eg==        NULL    NULL
        KQcNniTorf      Des Moines      NULL
2       QkXExqbMWZ5y9NWjO4PDYQ==        NULL    NULL
        u6792WT1MZ      Jefferson City  NULL
3       hLb2Ya9j+ayIpkCqWKqbCA==        NULL    NULL
        suR6IQZwLJ      Charleston      NULL
4       ctljLq7D2+h+nF52LvQDjA==        NULL    NULL
        yeMmNHuQca      Providence      NULL
5       ZGSoPIVwdya70f+qhuvsJg==        NULL    NULL
        XE3bw5Cjib      Juneau  NULL
6       8OgOf6opg38CEqRDCZVBkw==        NULL    NULL
        PQOXrqHyCP      Baton Rouge     NULL
7       kjwaxk7pXtCuOEXqBD56dw==        NULL    NULL
        IrKwoTqXnR      Carson City     NULL
8       IyQAknyGOO3hnvRnMAaWQw==        NULL    NULL
        5TdDMqAXrX      Providence      NULL
9       cxyNZFnBCs0nQwwI5Hj07A==        NULL    NULL
        OtWW4BdFVv      Raleigh NULL
10      jBXiI6c24f+s9hiWo52RYg==        NULL    NULL
        NiRnATHIWo      Augusta NULL
Time taken: 0.058 seconds, Fetched: 20 row(s)

```
hive> select Decrypt(firstname) from Encrypt_Test;

Theodore
NULL
Franklin
NULL
Dwight
NULL
Ronald
NULL
Woodrow
NULL
Richard
NULL
Lyndon
NULL
William
NULL
George
NULL
Harry
NULL
```

Comment: could you upload the formatted output? it's not obvious which null is a part of which column's output. and please upload the "describe" and "show create" outputs for tables "encrypt_test" and "stagging_encrypt"